# tortoisesvn unable to connect to repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet, subversion-edge

I am embarrassed to ask this question because of my knowledge and past experience and because of the popularity of the question. But I'm so frustrated I'm hoping someone can help me. I've spent hours on this already. I've searched the net, searched these forums, and read some documentation.

I am trying to get my TortoiseSVN client to work with my Collabnet Subversion Edge again after a few years of not doing any programming development. Everything runs on one Windows machine.

The Apache server and subversion server are both running (apparently fine), and I can easily access all my repositories with the two http: links on the Edge administration page. (https://host/svn and https://host/viewvc).

I have checked the httpd.conf files, and all the pathnames to the repositories seem to be correct. (Edge writes them out from the browser admin page.)

If I use a file:///xxx URL in Tortoise, I can see my repositories just fine, so they are well formed and not corrupted.

But the Tortoise client won't connect to the subversion server, no matter what syntax I try. I get a series of variations of the usual messages about not being able to connect to the URL, to the host, or to a repository, or whatever. The messages vary a bit depending on what I enter in the search bar.

The most popular messages are

```
(for svn://myhostname/myrep) "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

(for http://myhostname/myrep) "Unable to connect to a repository at URL xxx"
```

I've also cleared the Saved Data caches in TSVN where they seemed appropriate.

The frustrating thing was that all this software worked for a year or two in the past. I am hoping that someone can give me a few command lines to type, or a few files to check to get me going again. The only that has changed since everything worked was that I changed to a bigger disk drive, and changed the location of the repositories. Nothing else at all.

Thank you. Here's hoping...

Comment: An additional question for the record: if the syntax "file:///E:/Dropbox/big/Reps_SVN/my_sq_projects/trunk" works correctly, what syntax should be given on the TortoiseSVN URL line? "svn://host/something", "http://host/something", or either one?

Comment: I think the answer to my question is that Collabnet Edge does not start up a svnserve.exe service on Windows, so there is nothing for TortoiseSVN to connect to. Either that, or the collabnet svnserve.exe is listening on a special port that tortoise doesn't know about. I started up a svnserve.exe windows service manually, and everything works fine. I'll look further to see if collabnet actually starts a svnserve.exe service (I couldn't find one in the active processes on Windows.)

Comment: So the problem is that TortoiseSVN can't connect, but web browser can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [proxy settings](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-network) in TortoiseSVN, Windows Firewall and your antivirus on the workstation. Check that the URL to the repositories is correct, too. It has to look like `https://svn.example.com/svn/RepositoryName`.

Several (possibly) related comments:

- You must use HTTP(S) URL to address the repositories. SVN Edge does not support [`svnserve` (svn://)](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/svnserve/). It makes repositories available via HTTP(S) using [Apache HTTP Server (mod_dav_svn)](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/).
- Do **not** put your repositories and working copies to Dropbox. You should not use such services to store or backup live SVN repositories. Subversion repositories use flat file database system on disk and the services such as Dropbox interfere with file operations performed by SVN internally. This will cause various problems with the repositories and may also cause data loss.
- When you use [`file://` access schema](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/in-action/#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1) you don't even contact the server -- SVN client access the repository directly on filesystem.

Comment: You are right on all counts. (Especially for the syntax, which I _swear_ I tried before, with svn between the host and rep name. I remember it because I was prompted for an invalid certificate.) Anyway, I can access the reps all 3 ways now. Interesting about Dropbox; I wondered about that too, mostly because of the constant traffic that would be generated by Resharper, binaries, code, rep operations, etc. This is the first time in a decade I thought seriously about trying Dropbox. But with your comment, I'll probably abandon the idea... Thanks!